# how to write one regular expression for string replace

Tags: java, regex

I have one string and want to replace the values of password/salary to ****.
so can you help write one?

the source string may be:

```
password=12132&key=value
key=value&password=1212111&key2=value2
key=value&password=1212111
```

the salary is similar with password but can turn up with password such as:

```
key=value&password=1212111&key2=value2&salary=890
```

how to write: replace the password or salary's value to **** using replace all?
        str.replaceAll

thanks.

Comment: Use ```s.replaceAll("(?<=password=)[^&]*", "****")```.

Comment: @saka1029 Forgot "salary" and key start boundary: `s.replaceAll("(?<=(?:^|&)(?:password|salary)=)[^&]*", "****")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex pattern with `replaceAll()`. Please see this fiddle...

http://fiddle.re/r0cy76

Heres the pattern...

```
(?<=(?:^|&)(?:password|salary)=)[^&]*
```